# Multi join filters

Tags: marketing-cloud, relationships, filters

I would like to run a filter that involves data from more than one data extension.

Eg. I have three Data Extensions A, B, C and I would like to filter A by an attribute of C but A and C have not attributes in common.

Thus I created Data Relationships between A and B and between B and C.

For the first relation, I selected an attribute of A and the primary key of B and for the second relation I selected and attribute of B and the primary key of C.

My intention is to filter A for the primary key of C. I have set that both Data Relationships can be used in a Data Filter.

> My problem is that when I filter A for the primary key of C, the result is 0 records. However I know for sure the result must be 3.

Does anyone know if I’m following the correct procedure?

Comment: Can you confirm that each record in A, has a record in B ?
If there's no record in B, then it won't be able to find the C records.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use SQL to achieve it:

> SELECT a.Field1, a.Field2, a.Field3
>
> FROM DataExtensionA a
>
> INNER JOIN DataExtensionB b
> ON a.Key = b.Key
>
> LEFT JOIN DataExtensionC c
> ON b.OtherKey = c.OtherKey
>
> WHERE c.OtherKey is not null

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, all records in A are in B and all records in B are in C. The solution you suggest however is not dynamic, I need a solution that does not need to be updated in case A comes to have a fourth field.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this Julia? Otherwise i would be happy to look at this again.